# In Vaadin PDF does not work in popup Window

Tags: pdf, internet-explorer-9, vaadin

I am trying to display a PDF in a popup window using Vaadin 6.6.2 and the code as shown in this blog:

http://jcraane.blogspot.com/2010/09/printing-in-vaadin.html

The problem I have is that whenever I close the Window containing the PDF it always hangs the current browser tab in IE 9.

I have tested this in Safari, Firefox, and IE 8 and its works fine. I also know that the problem is related to the embedded PDF as I have tried replacing the embedded PDF with a Vaadin Label and then the popup window closes fine in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in Firefox 3.x, I solved it by upgrading to Firefox 4, and upgrading the Adobe plugin.

It seems to me the problem is on the browser/plug-in side.

If you are stuck with that browser/version, try just upgrading the plugin if that's not already on the latest version.

Comment: Hi all, any update on this issue? because i am facing the same problem.it works fine for me in google chrome..